# JdbcTemplate : How to return a java.util.Date in a formatted way

Tags: java, date, jdbc, jdbctemplate, date-formatting

I've been searching for the answer but no luck, I have a data saved in MySQL table as a `java.util.Date` like this way `2023-01-30` what I want to do is to retrieve that date and format it to `dd/MM/yyyy`, meaning when i retrieve the date should return me `30/01/2023`

**My Table:**

| id | name | release_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The Godfather | 2023-01-30 |
| 2 | The Good The Bad The Ugly | 2023-01-30 |

**This is my class:**

```
public record Movie(Integer id,
                    String name,
                    List<Actor> actors,
                    Date releaseDate) {
}
```

This is my method for searching a specific date and return a `movie` but with formatted `release_date`

```
public static final String DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy";

public List<Movie> selectMovieByDate() throws ParseException {

 String QUERY_GET_CONFIRM_JOURNEE = "select id, name, release_date from movie where date_format(release_date, '%Y/%M/%d') = date_format(?,  '%Y/%M/%d')";
 String stringDate = "2023-01-30";
 Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(stringDate);  
 String dateJournee = this.dateToString(date1, DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN);
 List<Movie> movies = this.getMovieDetail(QUERY_GET_CONFIRM_JOURNEE, jdbcTemplate,
 new Object[] {dateJournee});
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return movies;

}
```

**RowMapper method**

```
private List<Movie> getMovieDetail(String sql, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, Object[] params) {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    List<Movie> listDto = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new RowMapper() {
        @Override
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Movie detailPaiementDto = new Movie(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"),List.of(), rs.getDate("release_date"));
            return detailPaiementDto;
        }
    });
    return listDto;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have miss matching on date format. Thanks for response

Comment: You should be using `LocalDate` now and `DateTimeFormatter` not the old date classes, making your mapping code: `Movie detailPaiementDto = new Movie(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"),List.of(), rs.getObject("release_date", java.time.LocalDate.class));` Formatting might be done in `toString` for the date format you want

Comment: Also, there's no need to be worrying about formatting in the query. Set the parameter as `LocalDate`. If the original argument is in non-ISO format then use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse it

Comment: Obviously `date_format(release_date, '%Y/%M/%d') = date_format(?,  '%Y/%M/%d')` *should* work in SQL provided that both `release_date` and `?` are dates (which I don’t think they are in your case). But it’s a bit like doing `String.valueOf(x).equals(String.valueOf(2))` in Java instead of `x == 2`. So don’t. Use `release_date = ?`  and, as others have said, make sure that you are passing a `LocalDate` from Java.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. For a date-only value, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```java
public record Movie(
    Integer id,
    String name,
    List<Actor> actors,
    LocalDate releaseDate  // Never use either `Date` class. Use only java.time classes such as `LocalDate`.
) {}
```

## Think objects, not strings

Date-time objects hold date-time values, not text. Date-time objects do not have a “format”. You are thinking in terms of strings and text; learn to think in terms of objects.

Similarly, you should be passing *objects* to your JDBC calls, not mere strings. JDBC 4.2+ requires every driver to support the *java.time* classes. See the `setObject`/`getObject` methods on `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.